# Multi step form with devise and another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-step

I found this link : http://andymaleh.blogspot.nl/2013/10/ultra-light-maintainable-wizards-in.html

But I wonder if this idea can work if one of the steps is a devise step making a login name and password.

And if this can work, what do I have to change ?

Answer (score 3):

Slightly out of your question. But if you want to create a multi step form using devise then you can use https://github.com/schneems/wicked wicked gem as well. It's very easy to configure gem for multistep forms. You can find a good implementation here http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked?view=asciicast as well.